# Streaming H.264 over RTP (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, h.264, rtp, openmax

I need help using the RTP protocol for streaming H.264 video.
I have a Raspberry PI(B+) and a camera module. The Raspberry PI has a hardware encoder for H.264.

However, the player can't play RTP streams: the video have a delay and the picture is very bad :
[image]

I can't understand this problem.

There is stream H.264 :

```
[SPS]
[PPS]
[I-Frame]
[P-FRAME]
[P-FRAME]
[P-FRAME]
....
[SPS]
[PPS]
[I-Frame]
....
```

This stream I place in separate RTP packets. 
Log of VLC while playing:

```
[h264 @ 0x90bba80] error while decoding MB 19 14, bytestream (-3)
[h264 @ 0x90bba80] concealing 50 DC, 50 AC, 50 MV errors
[h264 @ 0x90bb680] error while decoding MB 19 14, bytestream (-3)
[h264 @ 0x90bb680] concealing 50 DC, 50 AC, 50 MV errors
[h264 @ 0x90bb680] error while decoding MB 19 14, bytestream (-3)
[h264 @ 0x90bb680] concealing 50 DC, 50 AC, 50 MV errors
```

For access to the hardware encoder I use OpenMax. Part of code for the encoder:

```
OMX_INIT_STRUCTURE(ep->encoder_portdef);
ep->encoder_portdef.nPortIndex = 201;
if((r = OMX_GetParameter(ctx->encoder, OMX_IndexParamPortDefinition, &ep->encoder_portdef)) != OMX_ErrorNone)
    die("Failed to get port definition for encoder output port 201");

ep->encoder_portdef.format.video.nFrameWidth = cp->camera_portdef.format.video.nFrameWidth;
ep->encoder_portdef.format.video.nFrameHeight = cp->camera_portdef.format.video.nFrameHeight;
ep->encoder_portdef.format.video.xFramerate = cp->camera_portdef.format.video.xFramerate;
ep->encoder_portdef.format.video.nStride = cp->camera_portdef.format.video.nStride;
ep->encoder_portdef.format.video.eCompressionFormat = OMX_VIDEO_CodingAVC;
ep->encoder_portdef.format.video.nBitrate = dp->video.bitrate;
if((r = OMX_SetParameter(ctx->encoder, OMX_IndexParamPortDefinition, &ep->encoder_portdef)) != OMX_ErrorNone)
    die("Failed to set port definition for encoder output port 201");

OMX_INIT_STRUCTURE(ep->bitrate);
ep->bitrate.eControlRate = OMX_Video_ControlRateVariable;
ep->bitrate.nTargetBitrate = ep->encoder_portdef.format.video.nBitrate;
ep->bitrate.nPortIndex = 201;
if((r = OMX_SetParameter(ctx->encoder, OMX_IndexParamVideoBitrate, &ep->bitrate)) != OMX_ErrorNone)
    die("Failed to set bitrate for encoder output port 201");

OMX_VIDEO_CONFIG_AVCINTRAPERIOD idr;
OMX_INIT_STRUCTURE(idr);
idr.nPortIndex = 201;
if((r=OMX_GetParameter(ctx->encoder, OMX_IndexConfigVideoAVCIntraPeriod, &idr)) != OMX_ErrorNone)
    die("Failed to get encoder params\n");
OMX_INIT_STRUCTURE(idr);
idr.nPortIndex = 201;
idr.nIDRPeriod = 30;
if((r=OMX_SetParameter(ctx->encoder, OMX_IndexConfigVideoAVCIntraPeriod, &idr)) != OMX_ErrorNone)
    die("Failed to get encoder params\n");
```

Resulting data from the encoder I send to the function, previously I remove starting code (00 00 00 01):

```
error = OMX_FillThisBuffer (encoder.handle, ctx.encoder_ppBuffer_out);
..................
buf = ctx.encoder_ppBuffer_out->pBuffer;
len = ctx.encoder_ppBuffer_out->nFilledLen;    
send_data_to_rtp((uint8_t*)&buf[4], len-4, 30);
```

Description function packing to RTP:

```
// titles
    #define BUF_SIZE        1500
    #define RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE    1400
    /* RTP HEADER */
    typedef struct{
        /* 1 byte */
        uint8_t csrc_len:    4;    
        uint8_t extension:    1;    
        uint8_t padding:    1;    
        uint8_t version:    2;    
        /* 2 byte */
        uint8_t payload_type:    7;    
        uint8_t marker:        1;    
        /* 3-4 */
        uint16_t seq_no;        
        /* 5-8 */
        uint32_t timestamp;        
        /* 9-12 */
        uint32_t ssrc;            
    }__attribute__ ((packed)) rtp_header;

    typedef struct {
        uint8_t type:        5;    
        uint8_t nri:        2;   
        uint8_t f:        1;   
    }__attribute__ ((packed)) nalu_header;

    typedef struct {
        uint8_t type: 5;
        uint8_t nri: 2;
        uint8_t f: 1;
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) fu_indicator;

    typedef struct {
        uint8_t type: 5;
        uint8_t r: 1;
        uint8_t e: 1;
        uint8_t s: 1;
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) fu_header;

// Create packet
static void send_data_to_rtp(uint8_t *data, int len, int framerate)
{
    static uint8_t sendbuf[BUF_SIZE];
    static uint32_t ts_current = 0;
    static uint16_t seq_num = 0;
    static uint16_t pack_num, last_pack_size, current_pack;
    uint8_t *nalu_playload;
    /* RTP HEADER */
    rtp_header *rtp_hdr;
    /* NALU HEADER */
    nalu_header *nalu_hdr;

    fu_indicator *fu_ind;

    fu_header *fu_hdr;

    ts_current += (90000 / framerate);
    memset(sendbuf, 0, sizeof(sendbuf));

    rtp_hdr = (rtp_header*)&sendbuf[0];
    rtp_hdr->version = 2;
    rtp_hdr->marker = 0;
    rtp_hdr->csrc_len = 0;
    rtp_hdr->extension = 0;
    rtp_hdr->padding = 0;
    rtp_hdr->ssrc = htonl(SSRC_NUM);
    rtp_hdr->payload_type = TYPE_H264;
    rtp_hdr->timestamp = htonl(ts_current);

    if (len <= RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE) {
        rtp_hdr->marker = 1;
        rtp_hdr->seq_no = htons(++seq_num);
        nalu_hdr = (nalu_header*)&sendbuf[12];

        nalu_hdr->type = data[0] & 0x1f;
        nalu_hdr->f = data[0] & 0x80;
        nalu_hdr->nri = data[0] & 0x60 >> 5;
        nalu_playload = (uint8_t*)&sendbuf[13];

        memcpy(nalu_playload, data + 1, len-1);

        send_data_client(sendbuf, len + 13);
    } else {
        pack_num = (len % RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE) ? (len / RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE + 1) : (len / RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE);
        /* data size in last packege */
        last_pack_size = (len % RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE) ? (len % RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE) : (RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE);
        current_pack = 0;

        fu_ind = (fu_indicator *)&sendbuf[12];
        fu_ind->f = data[0] & 0x80;
        fu_ind->nri = (data[0] & 0x60) >> 5;

        fu_ind->type = 28;
        fu_hdr = (fu_header *)&sendbuf[13];
        fu_hdr->type = data[0] & 0x1f;

        while (current_pack < pack_num) {

            rtp_hdr->seq_no = htons(++seq_num);
            /* first packet */
            if(current_pack == 0) {

                fu_hdr->s = 1, fu_hdr->e = 0, fu_hdr->r = 0;
                rtp_hdr->marker = 0;

                nalu_playload = (uint8_t*)&sendbuf[14];
                memset(nalu_playload, 0, RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE);
                memcpy(nalu_playload, data + 1, RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE);

                send_data_client(sendbuf, RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE + 14);
            } else if(current_pack < pack_num - 1){
                fu_hdr->s = 0, fu_hdr->e = 0, fu_hdr->r = 0;
                rtp_hdr->marker = 0;
                nalu_playload = (uint8_t*)&sendbuf[14];
                memset(nalu_playload, 0, RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE);
                memcpy(nalu_playload, data + (current_pack * RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE) + 1, RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE);

                send_data_client(sendbuf, RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE + 14);
            /* last packet */
            } else {
                rtp_hdr->marker = 1;
                nalu_playload = (uint8_t*)&sendbuf[14];
                fu_hdr->s = 0, fu_hdr->e = 1, fu_hdr->r = 0;
                memset(nalu_playload, 0, RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE);
                memcpy(nalu_playload, data + (current_pack * RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE) + 1, last_pack_size - 1);

                send_data_client(sendbuf, last_pack_size - 1 + 14);
            }
            current_pack += 1;
        }
    }
}

// Write data to socket
static void send_data_client(uint8_t *send_buf, size_t len_sendbuf)
{
    sendto(socket_fd, send_buf, len_sendbuf, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr));
}
```

Comment: Could be packet loss, You can check the RTCP RRs for packet loss. If your RTP sender doesn't give you access, you can sniff them on the network.

Comment: Is your encoder generating 1 NALU per buffer or is it producing a NALU byte stream?